# Backstack concept of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an app with navigation drawer. I have 3 fragments.

In my main activity, I call a fragment which is already a navigation item.
I clicked to all fragments from my navigation bar and when I press back button it goes to the previous fragment and goes to home fragment.

However, I want to go back to home fragment whenever i press back button in any fragment.

Let me know if I need to add more details.

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    TAG_FRAGMENT="Home";                      
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    fragment = new AboutUs();
                    TAG_FRAGMENT="About";
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,TAG_FRAGMENT).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_feedback:
                    fragment = new Feedback();
                    TAG_FRAGMENT="Feedback";
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,TAG_FRAGMENT).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;

            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            return true;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}




}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your code is very long, can you shorten it into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @OttToomet It wasn't that long, tbh.

Comment: 1.) fragment tag should be unique 2.) the backstack stores transactions that you can  "pop off", you probably want to use `popBackstackImmediate(transactionTag, 0)` (or inclusive).